# How can i hide a product category on woocommerce category list menu when all the products under this category are out of stock?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have checked from Woocommerce--> Inventory the option to hide "out of stock" products from my eshop. Now, i am trying to find out how i can hide a category from category list menu widget that has only out of stock products. Any idea? Thanks in advance. i use iks menu plugin.

I tried

```
function exclude_categories( $category_list_args ) {

$args = array(
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'hierarchical' => true,
);

$product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );

$exclude = array();
foreach ( $product_categories as $category ) {

    $posts         = get_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'product_cat' => $category->slug, 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
    $show_category = false;

    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {

        $product         = new wC_Product( $post );
        $visible_product = $product->is_visible();

        if ( true === $visible_product ) {
            $show_category = true;
            break;
        }

    }

    if ( false === $show_category ) {
        $exclude[] = $category->term_id;
    }

}

if ( ! empty( $exclude ) ) {
    $category_list_args['exclude'] = implode( ',', $exclude );
    unset( $category_list_args['include'] );
}

return $category_list_args;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_categories_widget_args', 'exclude_categories', 10, 1 );
```

Which hook should i use instead of woocommerce_product_categories_widget_args ? I use iks menus plugin to show on accordion the list of products categories. The code above works on Woocommerce Product Categories Widget but not on iks menu widget...

On iks menu plugin, the function that is responsible for showing the categories on widget sidebar is

```
private function get_WP_terms() {
    $taxonomy = $this->get_taxonomy();

    if ( $taxonomy ) {
        $this->args = [
            "taxonomy" => $taxonomy,
        ];
        $this->save_args( [
            "orderby",
            "order",
            "hide_empty",
            "hierarchical",
            "include",
            "exclude",
            "search",
            "child_of",
            "parent",
            "childless",
        ] );

        if ( version_compare( get_bloginfo( 'version' ), '4.5', '>=' ) ) {
            $items = get_terms( $this->args );
        } else {
            $items = get_terms( $taxonomy, $this->args );
        }

        if ( is_array( $items ) ) {
            if ( ! empty( $items ) ) {
                $index      = 0;
                $show_posts = $this->settings_manager->get_value( "show_posts" );

                /* Posts */
                if ( $show_posts ) {
                    $post_type   = Utils::get_post_type_by_taxonomy( $taxonomy );
                    $include     = $this->settings_manager->get_value( "include" );
                    $has_include = ! empty( $include );

                    $posts = get_posts( [
                        'post_type'        => $post_type,
                        'posts_per_page'   => - 1,
                        'orderby'          => 'date',
                        'order'            => 'DESC',
                        'tax_query'        => [
                            [
                                'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                                'operator' => $has_include ? 'IN' : 'EXISTS',
                                'terms'    => $has_include ? Utils::get_terms_ids( $items ) : [],
                            ]
                        ],
                         
                        'suppress_filters' => false // [Fix] WPML compatibility
                    ] );

                    $posts_by_terms = [];
                    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
                        $terms = get_the_terms( $post, $taxonomy );
                        if ( ! empty( $terms ) ) {
                            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                                if ( ! isset( $posts_by_terms[ $term->term_id ] ) ) {
                                    $posts_by_terms[ $term->term_id ] = [];
                                }
                                $posts_by_terms[ $term->term_id ][] = $post;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                foreach ( $items as $key => $item ) {
                    $id   = (int) $item->term_id;
                    $link = get_term_link( $id );

                    $item_data = [
                        "id"                    => $id,
                        "title"                 => $item->name,
                        "link"                  => $link,
                        "parent"                => (int) $item->parent,
                        "is_current"            => $this->is_current_page_url( $link ) || $this->get_queried_object_term_id() === $id,
                        "is_term_includes_post" => $this->is_term_includes_post( $id, $this->get_taxonomy() ),
                        "is_page_includes_post" => false,
                        "index"                 => $index,
                        "is_expanded"           => false,
                        "posts_count"           => $item->count,
                        "is_post"               => false,
                        "target"                => null,
                    ];
                    $index ++;

                    $this->data[] = $item_data;

                    if ( $show_posts ) {
                        if ( isset( $posts_by_terms[ $id ] ) ) {
                            $result_posts = $posts_by_terms[ $id ];
                            foreach ( $result_posts as $post ) {
                                $post_link    = get_permalink( $post->ID );
                                $this->data[] = [
                                    "id"                    => $post->ID,
                                    "title"                 => $post->post_title,
                                    "link"                  => $post_link,
                                    "parent"                => $id,
                                    "is_current"            => $this->is_current_page_url( $post_link ),
                                    "is_term_includes_post" => false,
                                    "is_page_includes_post" => false,
                                    "index"                 => $index,
                                    "is_expanded"           => false,
                                    "posts_count"           => false,
                                    "is_post"               => true,
                                    "target"                => null,
                                ];
                                $index ++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

i suppose that i need something like

```
  'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => '_stock_status',
        'value' => 'instock',
        'compare' => '=',
    )
)
```

but i am a little bit confused...

Comment: Have your tried `'hide_empty' => true,` ?

Comment: hello @Fresz, thank you for your comment but this does not work

Comment: https://chrisk.io/woocommerce-hide-categories-with-no-visible-products-in-the-product-category-widget/
Take a look at foreach loops - first is looping through the categories, the second is looping through the products - there is an option to check for visibility `$product->is_visible()`. I think from here you will know what to do :)

Comment: did you find solution?

Comment: hello @Fresz thank you for you time, no, i did not find a solution. i have tried the solution you suggested and it works only for Woocommerce Product Categories Widget but not on iks menu widget... I tried to change the get_posts(...) on function get_WP_terms() that is responsible on iks menu plugin for showing the categories on widget sidebar (pls see the code above) but unfortunately it did not work.

Comment: Sorry I meant to come back to this issue earlier but got caught up with other work. Just posted an answer - I just tested it and it works.

Answer (score 0):

The only way we can find the post count per category was by getting all categories (`terms`) of `product_cat`. Then we looped through them - each time calling my function `get_count` and passing `term_id`. In the `get_count` we run a query to get all posts associated with it and we also pass post meta `_stock_status = instock`. This return all products where the stock status is in stock. Then we return `found_posts` attribute back - the IF statement then checks is the post count is bigger than 0.

The code (tested):

```
add_shortcode('test_test','test_test');
function test_test() {

    $terms = get_terms('product_cat');

    foreach($terms as $term) {

        $post_count = get_count($term->term_id);

        if($post_count > 0) {
            echo $term->name . '<br>'; //This is where you put your category details
        }  
    }
}

function get_count($cat_id) {

    $args = array(
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => array($cat_id),
                'include_children' => false
              )
        ),
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'meta_key' => '_stock_status',
        'meta_value' => 'instock',
        'meta_compare' => '='
    );

    $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);

    wp_reset_postdata();

    return $wp_query->found_posts;

}
```